# Algorithm about struct on C

Tags: c, struct, program-entry-point

I'm trying to solve a question by using struct on C.

It should find the biggest one of 3 values, and if it is prime number, add to all others. If not just return biggest number to main function. I couldn't find where I did the mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct q {
    int a, b, c, max;
}d;

func(struct q d1)
{
    int max1;
    max1=0;
    int w=0;
    int i;
    if (d1.a>d1.b && d1.a>d1.c)
        max1=d1.a;
    if (d1.b>d1.a && d1.b>d1.c)
        max1=d1.b;
    if (d1.c>d1.b && d1.c>d1.a)
        max1=d1.c;

    for(i=2;i<max1;i++)
    {
        if (max1%i==0)
            w=1;
    }
    if (w==0)
    {
        d1.a=d1.a+max1;
        d1.b=d1.b+max1;
        d1.c=d1.c+max1;
    }
    if (w==1)
    {
            d1.max=max1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<1;i++)
    {
        d.max=0;
        puts("enter value of a b c:");
        scanf("%d %d %d",&d.a,&d.b,&d.c);
        func(d);
        if(d.max==0) printf("%d %d %d",d.a,d.b,d.c);
        else printf("%d",d.max);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I amn't sure about the algorithm logic. But the mistake is -

```
func(struct q d1) 

func(d);
```

`d1` is a copy of the passed parameter `d`. So, modifying `d1`, doesn't affect the passed the parameter `d`.

You should actually pass the address of object `d` to the function.

Comment: Means: pass a pointer to the function, modify the struct via the pointer to the struct not a copy of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

in func() you have to pass the address of the structure...
because if you pass only struct variable then its value is affected till that buffer only...